# Scrapy - How to convert the unicode on my output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm scraping a website and the titles have latin accents Ex: É, não, etc...

This is my code:

```
    for tank in response.xpath('//html/body/div/div[4]/div/div/div/table[1]/tr/td/div'):
        item = VapeItem()
        item["title"] = tank.xpath("h3/a/text()").extract()
```

And the Json Output example:

```
{"title": "HALO CAF\u00c9 MOCHA"},
```

Question is: How do I convert this so it shows up like this?

```
 {"title": "HALO CAFÉ MOCHA"},
```

I've tried encode("utf8") without success.

Comment: Where/How are you checking tht unicode output?

Comment: JSON I'm checking via my code editor (Sublime Text) and I also output it to csv and read it on excel.

Comment: FYI, you don't want `encode`. You've got it backwards. You need to `decode` as `utf-8` (to convert from bytes-like `str` data to `unicode`).

Comment: why would you want to convert it? the data you got is the real data, the decoding of that information isn't something you should do, because you will be corrupting the data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to just print it?

```
>>> print json.loads(txt)['title']

HALO CAFÉ MOCHA
```

Writing to a file works just as well, don’t really see the problem here.

```
>>> parsed_data = json.loads('{"title": "HALO CAF\u00c9 MOCHA"}')
>>> with open('foo.txt', 'w') as fin:
...   fin.write(parsed_data['title'].encode('utf-8'))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards. You need to `decode` as `utf-8` (to convert from bytes-like `str` data to `unicode`).

But that's not the real problem: `json` `dump` ensures ASCII compatible output by default (using escapes) to avoid problems with protocols that only handle ASCII (or can't rely on a specific encoding besides "ASCII compatible").

Pass [`ensure_ascii=False` to the `dump`/`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) call to allow it to output non-ASCII. Note the warnings on the docs; this can make some calls return `str`, others `unicode`, which may cause problems (on Py3, the issues aren't there; it's always `str`).